# Is there a concise way of removing rows in every group of a GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following data that closely resembles the [Pandas' Group By Tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Week' : [1, 2, 1, 2,
                                 1, 2, 1, 1],
                           'BloodType' : ['A+', 'AB', 'AB', 'B',
                                  'B', 'B+', 'AB', 'AB'],
                           'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                           'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

This produces a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

[image: Sample Data]

I want to group by the `"Week"` and then apply some operation to only the columns `C` and `D`. So I tried:

```
week_group = df.groupby('Week')
week_group.apply(lambda x: x.drop(["BloodType", "Week"], 1))
```

Which I originally interpreted as for every `DataFrame` drop the `"BloodType"` and `"Week"` column and give me the resulting group. However, it gives me:

[image: Sample apply]

However, I would have expected it to give me a `Group`, where each index was a `DataFrame` with only columns `C` and `D`. I did not expect a `DataFrame`.

I tried switching out `apply` with `transform` and `agg` which gave:

```
ValueError: transform must return a scalar value for each group
```

and:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 5
```

respectively. Is there a relatively simple transformation that can remove rows by name for each `DataFrame` in in a pandas `Group` and return the resulting `Group` object (or perform the operation in place)?

Comment: `df.groupby("Week")[("C", "D")]` isn't what you want?

Comment: @CJ59: I have a bigger data set where I want to drop about 4 things and keep about 700 others. Is there a way to get the compliment? But otherwise, yes.

Comment: @CJ59 I got it to work thanks for the help!

Comment: NP, the answer below is how I'd have done it exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of CJ59's answer I came up with this concise solution:

```
week_group = week_group[df.columns.difference(["Week", "BloodType"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps searching for

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Week'):
    print(name, group.drop(columns=['Week', 'BloodType']))

1           C         D
0  0.496714 -0.469474
2  0.647689 -0.463418
4 -0.234153  0.241962
6  1.579213 -1.724918
7  0.767435 -0.562288
2           C        D
1 -0.138264  0.54256
3  1.523030 -0.46573
5 -0.234137 -1.91328
```

Comment: This is a method that works, although I was pretty convinced that there was a non-loopy way of doing it. See my answer. Nonetheless, thanks for the input.

Comment: I see, but note that the loop is not really part of the solution to get rid of some columns. The dropping is just done while using a loop which I assume you'll need anyway for processing your groups.